# How to use packageScan and Persistence.xml together for EntityManagerFactory?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to use packageScan property. If I use like below, I'm getting below error. But if I uncomment the  property in persistence.xml, then it is working.

Can't I use persistence.xml and packageToScan property together?

```
 Not an managed type: class org.entities.Person
```

Config.java

```
@Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setPersistenceXmlLocation("persistence.xml");
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("sample");
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"org.entities"});
        return em;
    }
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="sample" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <!--<class>org.entities.Person</class>-->

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="user" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Hibernate" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: you don't. The JavaDoc of `setPackagesToScan(…)` states (emphasis mine):

> Set whether to use Spring-based scanning for entity classes in the classpath *instead* of using JPA's standard scanning of jar files with `persistence.xml` markers in them.

The mechanism basically builds up a default JPA `PersistenceUnitInfo` in the absence of a standard JPA `persistence.xml` and thus can't be combined with it.